# How to rerun the whole dag in case specific subtask failed on airflow

Tags: airflow

Hi I have dag in Airflow contain 5 subtasks , what I need to do is in case the subtask number 3 failed then wait till the minute became 45 then re trigger the dag from the beginning, is that possible in airflow?

I see we can put retry as global in the dag but in this case the failed subtask will retry only what I want is to re trigger all the dag from the beginning at spisific minute

Comment: According to the design [best practices](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html): *You should treat tasks in Airflow equivalent to transactions in a database. This implies that you should never produce incomplete results from your tasks.* It may be achieved via some aggregate task that will be a downstream for all, wait until desired time and clear all task instances to be rescheduled. But it will be hard to manage and maintain